# Printing the values of the array in html.erb file in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

Im trying to write code to print the contents of the `@lp_array` array in the html.erb file but it's not printing anything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Blalalala</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please check the items <br><br></h1>

        <% @lp_array.each do |lp|
                puts lp
            end
         %>

    </body>
</html>
```

The contents of the array is:

```
["LPAD736954", "LPAD762667", "LPAD723626", "LPAD737590", "LPAD737593", "LPAD765808", "LPAA550163", "LPAD737675", "LPAD843011", "LPAD723593", "LPAD720060", "LPAD737605", "LPAD731967", "LPAD761385", "LPAD731914", "LPAD721120", "LPAD736970", "LPAD765586", "LPAD765579", "LPAD720104", "LPAD723598", "LPAD779847", "LPAD762699"]
```

and I'd like to print each element in a new line. How should I print that ?

Comment: @ruby_newbie the you can just do <% instead of <%-

Comment: Puts will print things in server's log , on "std out" .
Write each line of your ruby between <% ------ %> and put a = like so :
 <%=--------%> when you want your ruby to be printed in html .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any time that you write ruby in erb you have to remember to use the correct tag.  So change your view to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Blalalala</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please check the items <br><br></h1>

        <%- @lp_array.each do |lp| %>
                <%= lp %>
            <%- end %>

    </body>
</html>
```

notice that the "=" in the erb tag tells the view to actually show the variable.  The "-" in the erb tag tells the view not to show the variable.  To print each to a new line you can use <br> or use CSS. for 
  just add one to the loop like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Blalalala</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please check the items <br><br></h1>

        <%- @lp_array.each do |lp| %>
                <%= lp %><br>
            <%- end %>

    </body>
</html>
```